# how to set particular index in list of media souces in exo player?

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x

Hi I installed `ExoPlayer V2` and I have Array list of size 10(like 10 songs) but when start `ExoPlayer` the audio media player always start first song instated of the specified index or position(I need to start 5th song)

```
for (ModelRadio sample : modelRadios) {
     MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(sample.get_radio_url()));
            concatenatingMediaSource.addMediaSource(mediaSource);
     }

player.seekTo(5); // i don't know this method will work or not?
player.prepare(concatenatingMediaSource);
player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

Comment: Don't use `player.seekTo(5);` for play 5th song

Comment: You need to get the path of 5th song and set in to `MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(SONG_PATH));`

Comment: `player.seekTo(5);` use for playing song from specific position.

Comment: then how  next button 6th and previous button 4th song will detects ? your ans wont work!!

Comment: Add your code in player complete listener for next song

Comment: And for previous song you need to play manually

Comment: no need to write manual code because it built in support next and previous in for loop

Answer (score 4):

i got answer from github

```
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.C;
player.seekTo(5, C.INDEX_UNSET);
player.prepare(concatenatingMediaSource, false, false);
player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

Comment: This helped. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to @Para M's answer.

> player.seekTo(5)

Starts the to be played track at 5 milliseconds

> player.seekTo(5, C.INDEX_UNSET)

Set the windowIndex (which is the index of the playlist) to 5 and the 2nd parameter determines where to start (in Ms) the audio track. I dont think you should be using index_unset as it is a constant with value -1 and just happens to start the track at the beginning.

If you want to use this method to start your playlist at track index 5 and have no need for starting your track at a certain time i think you might just as well use:

> player.seekToDefaultPosition(5)

Answer (score 1):

For my situation, this worked:

```
player?.prepare(mediaSource)
player?.playWhenReady = true
player?.seekToDefaultPosition(index)
```

That's to say, calling seekToDefault after calling prepare method helped

Comment: `.prepare(mediaSource)` is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

```
player.seekTo(int mediaItemIndex, long positionMs);
```

mediaItemIndex is the index of your song list,and positionMs is the exact start play position when you start playing.

For example , if you want to start playing at 10s of your song , just set like this

```
player.seekTo(int mediaItemIndex, 10000);
```